# Gap in my understanding of composition, types not matching

Tags: function, haskell, lambda, function-composition

In my code I need to sort a list of `(Int, Int)`'s by the value of the second element.

It's easy enough to do `sorted = sortBy (\(_,a) (_,b) -> compare a b) listOfPairs`, but I hate writing lambda's like this and I need to use this same lambda in a few places in my code.

So I tried to create two helpful functions that I will end up using in many places as follows (and I couldn't find them in the prelude):

```
-- apply a function of one argument to two different arguments and return a pair
fBoth :: (a -> b) -> a -> a -> (b,b)
fBoth f a b = (f a, f b)

-- pass elements of a pair to a function of two arguments
expandPair :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a,b) -> c
expandPair f (a,b) = f a b
```

Now I thought I would be able to compose something together to pass to `sortBy` instead of an ugly "extractor" lambda. But I cant quite get the types to line up.

I feel like I want to compose `(expandPair compare)` with `(fBoth snd)`, because `:t expandPair compare = (a,a) -> Ordering` and `:t fBoth snd = (a,b) -> (a,b) -> (b,b)`. I would think that the resulting type of this composition would be `(a,b) -> (a,b) -> Ordering` which I can pass to `sortBy`, but it doesn't quite work.

If I try to do `sortBy ((expandPair compare) . (fBoth snd)) [(1,2),(3,4)]` it gives me type errors. But what confuses me is that if I do `expandPair compare $ fBoth snd (1,2) (3,4)` it actually works and yields `LT` as expected.

So clearly I'm not understanding something about function composition here... I get the whole "g composed with f = g(f(x))" but I'm having trouble making it work for me here.

Alternatively, if there's an even simpler way to accomplish this particular task of sorting a list of pairs by the second element, I'd be interested in hearing that as well.

Comment: Try `sortBy (comparing snd) listOfPairs`. You'll need to import `Data.Ord`.

Comment: `expandPair` is the same as `uncurry`, it has the exact same definition, too.

Comment: `fBoth` is something that you should easily find in `Lens` package.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, your `expandPair` function is literally the same definition as `uncurry`, which is in `Prelude`.

The problem here is that `fboth snd` takes 2 arguments, so the normal composition operator is not quite suited for this task.  However, you can make a rather strange looking operator that lets you "compose" a function that takes two arguments with a function that takes 1 argument:

```
(.:) :: (c -> d) -> (a -> b -> c) -> a -> b -> d
(.:) = (.).(.)
```

The easy mnemonic for remembering this is that the function on the side with one dot takes 1 argument, of the same type as the output of the function that takes two arguments, which is on the side with two dots.  You can then write this as

```
sortBy (uncurry compare .: fboth snd) [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
```

Now, I will say that it's best not to really think about how the `.:` operator works, just look at its type rather than its definition.  It does come in handy fairly often, I use it pretty regularly and I certainly didn't come up with this operator.

---

You can also implement it as

```
> :m +Data.Function
> sortBy (compare `on` snd) ...
-- sortBy (on compare snd) ...
```

But as @mhwombat has pointed out, `Data.Ord` has an alias for `on compare` called `comparing`:

```
> :m +Data.Ord
> sortBy (comparing snd) ...
```

which is my preference.

---

Something that might make this operator a little more clear:

```
> :t (id .: (,))
a -> b -> (a, b)
> (id .: (,)) 1 2
(1, 2)
> (fst .: (,)) 1 2
1
> (snd .: (,)) 1 2
2
> (negate .: (+)) 1 2
-3
```

Comment: I like to at least think of (.:) as being defined `fmap . fmap` over the function Functor. That makes the most operational sense (to me).

Comment: @J.Abrahamson Interestingly, you can also define it as `(.:) = fmap fmap fmap`, which has the more general type of `(Functor f, Functor g) => (a -> b) -> f (g a) -> f (g b)`.  I'm not entirely sure what other functors it'd be useful for, but it is interesting that it can be defined that way.

Comment: When you define it as `fmap fmap fmap` then the first `fmap` gets specialized to `(.)` anyway. It is pretty cute, though.

Comment: @bheklilr For example `(fmap fmap fmap) succ [("a", 1), ("b", 10)]` is `[("a", 2), ("b", 11)]`.

Comment: oooh I never realized the comma is still just a normal operator... using it like `(,) 1 2` is pretty neat

Answer (score 0):

In the particular case of `compare` what your're looking an pplication of th `on` function from [`Data.Function`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-Function.html#v%3aon):

```
>>> :t (`on` snd)
(`on` snd) :: (b -> b -> c) -> (a, b) -> (a, b) -> c

>>> :t (compare `on` snd)
(compare `on` snd) :: Ord b => (a, b) -> (a, b) -> Ordering
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't think to look in Data.Function